# How to resize text to fit into container

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current approach but the problem is that I need to add 10px to make the text seem a decent size as they come out really small, which isn't super great on the smaller font sizes.

HTML

```
<div class="chapter-title"> text goes here </div>
```

JS function that is called on resize

```
    var chapterTitle = this.$('.chapter-title');
    var fontSize = chapterTitle.css("font-size");
    var charCount = chapterTitle.text().replace(/ /g,'').length;

    fontSize = (chapterTitle.width()/charCount) + 10;
    chapterTitle.css('font-size', fontSize)
```

does anyone know of a better approach to this? The text is dynamic, so if it's only a small amount of text I don't want make the font smaller, only if the text doesn't fit.

Comment: You can resize font based on CSS and @media size. Is the font too small on big/small monitors or in some specific application UI/scenario?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want here. You just wish to add 10 to the px font-size of the text on small screens?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just change the fontsize via CSS?

If the issue is for small text I would add a media query in the CSS to change the font-size.

```html
.chapter-title{
  font-size:18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .chapter-title{
    font-size:24px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need it do be dependent on the amount of characters, the text is dynamic